How to define a Healthcare protocol with multiple steps as a single FHIR resource?
I need to define a FHIR resource for a Healthcare Protocol with multiple steps.
Suppose the Protocol is as follow :

Take observation of a patient for the first time. Based on the observation, prescribe a medicine, and schedule another appointment for one month later.
After one month, based on the observations, prescribe another medicine with the previous one, and another appointment is scheduled for one month later.

This goes on for a couple of months.
I need a resource or a complete flow by which i can predefine the protocol, and suggest the steps to the practitioner, who will instruct the patient accordingly.
I tried using the PlanDefinition resource that contains multiple ActivityDefinition resources as actions. But then there will be multiple PlanDefinition resources for a single protocol.
I explored Workflows in FHIR as well. But as per my understanding, they were just using Task resource back and forth to manage the actions. ref
I need something that can contain a complete protocol, and handle the logic part (i.e., take action based on observation value of the patient) as well.
Is there a way to achieve that usecase?

PlanDefinition.action is recursive, so you should be able to define as deep and complex a hierarchy as you need for your protocol with a single resource.  The only reason to break into multiple resources is there are pieces of a protocol you want to be reused and shared across multiple protocols.
